# How can I resolve a firebase problem in iOS library?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, sdk

For our project we're creating an iOS framework, this project also requires Firebase as a third party library and when we try to add our library in a separate project Xcode throws us an error because it can't recognize Firebase.

Error:

> No such module 'Firebase' x86_64-apple-ios-simulator.swiftinterface

Failed to build module 'Project' for importation due to the errors above; the textual interface may be broken by project issues or a compiler bug

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

To build a framework, you need to create a universal aggregate framework to support both the simulator and physical device.

Try to create an aggregate framework in your project and run.